# Casseiopa template - Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: joomla-4.x, javascript, bootstrap, html, cassiopeia

I am trying to display a carousel in an article using the bootstrap code.

This is a new Joomla 4 install using the casseiopa template. Here is my code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div id="homePageCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="images/homepage/image1.jpg" loading="lazy" width="626" height="440" data-path="local-images:/homepage/humument.jpg"/>
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <p>Caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
   <img src="images/homepage/image2.jpg" loading="lazy" width="626" height="440" data-path="local-images:/homepage/con_grosso.jpg"/>
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <p>Caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#homePageCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
</button>
<button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#homePageCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
</button>
```

There are no JS errors and the mark up is all there with the correct images but the carousel doesn't slide. Even if you click the "next" button?

Do I need to initialise it somehow? Here is the JS stack btw in the header:

```
<script src="/media/mod_menu/js/menu-es5.min.js?48ca03fa0e3b50d7aa4e5f89b9c52113" nomodule="" defer=""></script>
<script src="/media/vendor/jquery/js/jquery.min.js?3.6.3"></script>
<script src="/media/legacy/js/jquery-noconflict.min.js?04499b98c0305b16b373dff09fe79d1290976288"></script>
<script type="application/json" class="joomla-script-options loaded">{"joomla.jtext":{"ERROR":"Error","MESSAGE":"Message","NOTICE":"Notice","WARNING":"Warning","JCLOSE":"Close","JOK":"OK","JOPEN":"Open"},"system.paths":{"root":"","rootFull":"http:\/\/test-tomphillips.dreamhosters.com\/","base":"","baseFull":"http:\/\/test-tomphillips.dreamhosters.com\/"},"csrf.token":"ed896ea8e6ad30bc3e01d7df0a107698"}</script>
<script src="/media/system/js/core.min.js?576eb51da909dcf692c98643faa6fc89629ead18"></script>
<script src="/media/templates/site/cassiopeia/js/template.min.js?48ca03fa0e3b50d7aa4e5f89b9c52113" defer=""></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/messages-es5.min.js?44e3f60beada646706be6569e75b36f7cf293bf9" nomodule="" defer=""></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/messages.min.js?7425e8d1cb9e4f061d5e30271d6d99b085344117" type="module"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Casseiopa already uses `use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;`.  So you can insert anywhere `HTMLHelper::_('bootstrap.carousel');` To initiate the bootstrap 5 carousel included in Joomla 4.

You can refer to the joomla documentation https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Using_Bootstrap_Components_in_Joomla_4#Carousel.

You can also follow this link with a tutorial on the subject :
https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Using_Bootstrap_Components_in_Joomla_4#Approach_2:_Using_a_Content_Plugin

hoping this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I use a free module to activate the Bootstrap components where en when needed, very handy: https://github.com/ceford/j4xdemos-mod-custom-bscompos

And then I read the bootstrap documentation and try the examples:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/